# Search subdocument of document in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to search using subdocument's property of document with this following code:

```
Model.UserRole.aggregate(
[
    {
        $match : {
            status : { $in : ["inactive"] },
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup : {
            from: "users",
            localField: "user",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "user"
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind : "$user"
    },
    {
        $match : { "user.name" : { $text: { $search: keyword } } }
    }
], function(err, result) {
    callback(null, result);
});
```

It gives me this error:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection
>   (rejection id: 1): MongoError: bad query: BadValue: unknown operator:
>   $text

I can't find any working code out there. Any advise everyone?

Comment: A normal string to be searched..

Comment: What is the structure of your document, and have you created text index on collection, bcoz $text works for text index.

Comment: Yeah I have done all of them..

Comment: I forgot to tell that  indexes are used only in the first stage of the pipeline. you can still search after $unwind for the text and get the desired results, but it won't use an index. so search using regex after unwind

Comment: Kindly share a sample document.

Answer (score 0):

You should use regex for searching after $unwind, as indexes are used only in the first stage of the pipeline.

Try code mentioned below

```
Model.UserRole.aggregate(
[
    {
        $match : {
            status : { $in : ["inactive"] },
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup : {
            from: "users",
            localField: "user",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "user"
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind : "$user"
    },
    {
        $match : { "user.name" : new RegExp(keyword, 'i') }
    }
], function(err, result) {
    callback(null, result);
});
```

Comment: If you can share a sample document structure and desired output you want, I can then check it on my pc and give you  solution